# How to call something/a creature looking like a human, but which isn't?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

How to call something/a creature looking like a human, but which isn't?
With "looking like" I mean its shape/appearance is very similar to a human, but without clearly being a human.

Do I just say: "It looks humanly"? or "It looks anthropomorphic"?
I want to answer the question: "What does it look like?", with a short understandable answer, without describing in detail, but with clearly stating out it isn't a human, even though its shape is similar to one.

Comment: *Humanoid* is reasonable (but the answer was deleted). There are such things as [*humanoid robots*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid_robot).

Comment: "Humanoid" is commonly used to mean "human-like".  (It doesn't imply any genetic relation to humans.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe I am implying to much meaning into it, because of my previous "experiences" with this word. But what about my suggestions? Is it legit or "good" to say anthropomorphic? Didn't know this word before, but translation tool spat it out.

Comment: _human-like_ satisfies your requirements, while being simple and easily understandable.

Comment: **Anthropomorphic** is most often used when people are imagining that something we know is NOT like a human has human characteristics—for gods and pets, especially. So Zeus is an anthropomorphic god, and Mickey Mouse is an anthropomorphized rodent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also call it [*android*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/android) or [*anthropoid*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anthropoid).

`adj.`

Possessing human features.

(...)

or

`adj.`

(...)

Resembling a human, especially in shape or outward appearance.

(...)

respectively

---

Both words are of Greek origin.

In the first case the stem is άνδρας (ándras), meaning *man*, in the second it's άνθρωπος (ánthropos), meaning *human*, both followed by the suffix -oid, also of Greek origin, originally appearing as -οειδής (-oidís), used to connote resemblance, of any kind.

Same suffix appeared in the other answer, the one JOSH provided but subsequently removed, namely *humanoid*. Only difference is the stem is in this case of Latin origin: *homo*, as in *Homo Sapiens* and the like...

(In fact, [*hominoid*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hominoid) does also exist).

So far, the only *semantic* reason to avoid the use of *android*, and opt for either of the other two, is if your creature resembles a *woman*, a case that isn't really covered by *android*, due to its "masculine" heritage.

Then there are other alternatives such as *anthropomorphic*, that you mention yourself, or its twin brother, *anthropomorphous* - suffixes "-morphic" and "-morphous", deriving from Greek μορφή (morfí), meaning shape, looks, connoting resemblance, only of the apparent kind.

In modern English, you could, of course, go with a less intricate word, such as [*manlike*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manlike).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link to android is referring to "big talk" ;) I think android is not the correct one, because it is describing more  a human like robot, what this creature isn't (it's rather out of flesh). Anthropoid I didn't know before, but is this a "common/known" word? Because the explanation referring much to apes.

Comment: anthropoid +1 - Of an image, statue, robot, or other inanimate object: shaped like or resembling a human being (OED)

Comment: @Artery Link fixed. As for the rest: Don't really know what [this](https://books.google.gr/books?id=BA_mZMJFnjgC&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq="an+android+creature"&source=bl&ots=hlu_rQJre_&sig=1qAkddybXePf2NwHPc4Z1VO0QG8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj06vLd1czQAhVIMBoKHd6GA7kQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=%22an%20android%20creature%22&f=false) is, but an "_an Android creature which had been dormant in the Lower Astral for a million years_" doesn't really sound like a robot...

Comment: @Artery .,,Neither does "[a huge anthropoid creature, covered with shaggy red brown hair](https://books.google.gr/books?id=j1hJAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq="anthropoid+creature"&source=bl&ots=ZA10d0fXXD&sig=eKvzRXFbAXsuxnRAd5mk0SY4L8A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOwJGS1szQAhWLWBoKHaE1CcsQ6AEIMDAG#v=onepage&q=%22anthropoid%20creature%22&f=false)"

Comment: Haha, okay :D Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of android due to the explanations of the first link with referring to robots and science-fiction. Because that's the same which comes into my mind, if I think about an android.

Answer (score 4):

*Humanoid* would be a good word for "human-shape" or "looking like a human."

From Merriam-Wenster:

> [*humanoid*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humanoid):
>   having human form or characteristics

**Note**: I acknowledge that both Mick and Hot Licks mentioned *humanoid* in comments on the question.

Comment: I edited your answer by adding a definition from an authoritative source. That's what expected on this site. Please review my edit and try to follow the format next time you answer a question. Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony I followed your lead.

Answer (score 2):

***Humanlike*** is a simple term to satisfy your requirement.

TFD:

> *Adj*.**1**. **[humanlike](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/humanlike)** - suggesting human characteristics for animals or inanimate things.